# How to pass a dataframe as object and as string in a function

Tags: r, function, pins

**I would like to customize the `pin_write` function from `pins` package:**

The original works this way:

```
library(pins)

# create board: 
board_versioned <-  board_folder("your path", versioned = TRUE)

board_versioned %>% 
  pin_write(iris, "iris")

# gives:
# Guessing `type = 'rds'`
# Creating new version '20221030T182552Z-f2bf1'
# Writing to pin 'iris'
```

Now I want to create a custom function:

```
library(pins)
my_pin_write <- function(board, df) {
  board %>% 
    pin_write(df, deparse(substitute(df)))
}

my_pin_write(board_versioned, iris)

#gives: 
# Guessing `type = 'rds'`
# Replacing version '20221030T182736Z-f2bf1' with '20221030T182750Z-f2bf1'
# Writing to pin 'df'
```

The problem is **Wrting to pin 'df'** .
I would expect:
**Writing to pin 'iris'**

I can't manage how to pass the dataframe as name as string in this situation. Many thanks!

Comment: You are using a pipe call. In that case the `df` will be searched within the piped environment, and if not found, use `df` You have 2 options, do not use the pipe, ie `pin_write(board, df, deparse(substitute(df)))` for `substitute` to use the function enviironment or if you use the pipe, call the `substitute` function outside of the pipe. eg `nm <- deparse(substitute(df))` and then do `board %>% pin_write(df, nm)`. You could decide to use the `rlang::enxpr` function: `board %>%pin_write(df, deparse(rlang::enxpr(df)))`

Comment: @onyambu. Very useful. Please send as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a pipe call. In that case the df will be searched within the piped environment, and if not found, use df You have 2 options, do not use the pipe, ie

```
 pin_write(board, df, deparse(substitute(df)))
```

for substitute to use the function environment or if you use the pipe, call the substitute function outside of the pipe. eg

```
nm <- deparse(substitute(df))
board %>% 
   pin_write(df, nm)
```

You could decide to use the rlang::enxpr function:

```
 board %>%
   pin_write(df, deparse(rlang::enxpr(df)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
my_pin_write <- function(board, df) {
  board %>% 
     pin_write(df, rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(df)))
 }
```

-testing

```
> my_pin_write(board_versioned, iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace `magrittr`'s pipe (`%>%`) by the R native pipe (`|>`) that is available since R 4.1.0.

```r
library(pins)

board_versioned <-  board_folder("your path", versioned = TRUE)

my_pin_write <- function(board, df) {
  board |>
    pin_write(df, deparse(substitute(df)))
}

my_pin_write(board_versioned, iris)
#> Guessing `type = 'rds'`
#> Creating new version '20221031T091813Z-911fb'
#> Writing to pin 'iris'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>